# Remove/ List all Keyboard Shortcuts VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

Someone in our office has assigned a macro to Ctrl+D.  This is frustrating, as it already has a function in Excel.

Excel makes it easy for you to assign a macro in Developer> Macros, and I'm aware that if I push options in this menu I can see which keys are assigned where.  The list of macros in this workbook is sizable, and I don't want to open each separately.

Is this listed anywhere?  I assume there's a log with this somewhere?  This is the closest I can find on msdn, but I need macros assigned in a macroworkbook: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh179479(v=nav.90).aspx

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/how-to-list-keyboard-shortcuts-assigned-to/5928fc4f-ae30-469f-86a0-70a332e3be1e?auth=1

Comment: Check out [this page](http://excel.tips.net/T003162_List_of_Macro_Shortcuts_in_All_Open_Workbooks.html) as well

Comment: First to write up their answer gets the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @GSerg for pointing this out, I will post this here for completeness to close the question.  Source is here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.worksheet.functions/TwcT-IlWjVk

```
To use this Macro (Sub), <alt-F8> opens the macro dialog box. Select the macro by name, and <RUN>. 
=================================================== 
Option Explicit 
'MUST set to Trust Access to the VBA Project Object Model 
'  in Excel Options 
'Set reference to: 
'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 
'Microsoft Scripting Runtime 
'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 
Sub ListMacroShortCutKeys() 
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject 
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent 
    Dim CodeMod As CodeModule 
    Dim LineNum As Long 
    Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind 
    Dim sProcName As String, sShortCutKey As String 
    Const FN As String = "C:\Temp\Temp.txt" 
    Dim S As String 
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject 
    Dim TS As TextStream 
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match 

Set RE = New RegExp 
With RE 
    .Global = True 
    .IgnoreCase = True 
    .Pattern = "Attribute\s+(\w+)\.VB_ProcData\.VB_Invoke_Func = ""(\S+)(?=\\)" 
End With 

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject 
Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject 
For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents 
    Select Case VBComp.Type 
        Case Is = vbext_ct_StdModule 
            VBComp.Export FN 
            Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(FN, ForReading, Format:=TristateFalse) 
            S = TS.ReadAll 
            TS.Close 
            FSO.DeleteFile (FN) 
            If RE.Test(S) = True Then 
                Set MC = RE.Execute(S) 
                For Each M In MC 
                    Debug.Print VBComp.name, M.SubMatches(0), M.SubMatches(1) 
                Next M 
            End If 
    End Select 
Next VBComp 
End Sub 
==============================
```

Answer (score -1):

Press ALT+F11 goto your project module. You can find here shortcuts vba macro coding. if you want to keep it then no need to do otherwise you can select all and delete and save and close the file.

Comment: Where abouts exactly in the macro coding?

Comment: In module you can find the macro coding.